# skip_before_action and Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncontroller

I just upgraded to Rails 5 and everything went pretty smoothy but for no apparent reason a method that is called after `skip_before_action` is not allowing rspec to run with this message

> Before process_action callback :redirect_heroku_user has not been defined (ArgumentError)

It is super strange because it works just fine on rails 4. Here is my code:

```
# application_controller.rb
def redirect_heroku_user
  redirect_to root_path if heroku_user?
end 

# some_controller.rb
skip_before_action :redirect_heroku_user, only: :edit
```

Comment: Do you have a before_action :redirect_heroku_user somewhere else? I think the actual error is telling you that you can't skip the before_action because the before_action was never actually set. I might be wrong, but adding rails: false as the suggested answers feels like something you shouldn't do unless you actually need it for production.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/500)

> [ActiveSupport::Callbacks#`skip_callback` now raises an ArgumentError if an unrecognized callback is removed.](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/6dfab475ca230dfcad7a603483431c8e7a8f908e/activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb#L634)

So your solution is to pass `raise: false` option to `skip_before_action`:

```
skip_before_action :redirect_heroku_user, raise: false
```

See the [changelog](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.0.0.beta1/activesupport/CHANGELOG.md) for more info.

Answer (score 6):

In Rails 5, if the method `redirect_heroku_user` is not defined in the same controller, then it raises this exception.

You can pass `raise: false` to avoid it as [mentioned here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/clearance/issues/621):

```
skip_before_action :redirect_heroku_user, only: :edit, raise: false
```